# Show that two conditional distributions are the same

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, multinomial-distribution

Let $\mathbf{Y}=\begin{pmatrix}
 \mathbf{Y_1}\\\mathbf{Y_2}
\end{pmatrix}\sim N\left (\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\Sigma} \right ), $ $\boldsymbol{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
 \boldsymbol{\mu_1}\\\boldsymbol{\mu_2}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}=\begin{pmatrix}
 \boldsymbol{\Sigma_{11}}& \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} \\
 \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12}& \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}$ are are compatibly partitioned. Making a variable transform
$$\left(\begin{array}{l}
\boldsymbol{U}_{1} \\
\boldsymbol{U}_{2}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\boldsymbol{I} & -\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1} \\
\mathbf{0} & \boldsymbol{I}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\boldsymbol{Y}_{1} \\
\boldsymbol{Y}_{2}
\end{array}\right)-\begin{pmatrix}
 \boldsymbol{\mu}_{1}\\
 \boldsymbol{\mu}_{2}\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The conditional distribution of $\boldsymbol{X_{1}}$ given $ \boldsymbol{X_{2}} $ denote as $\boldsymbol{X}_{1} \mid \boldsymbol{X}_{2}.$Symbol $\boldsymbol{X}_{1} \stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=}\boldsymbol{X}_{2} $ means two random variables $\boldsymbol{X}_{1} $  and $\boldsymbol{X}_{2}$ have the same distribution.

Show that $$\boldsymbol{Y}_{1} \mid \boldsymbol{Y}_{2}\stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=}\left[\boldsymbol{U}_{1}+\boldsymbol{\mu}_{1}+\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1} \boldsymbol{U}_{2}\right] \mid \boldsymbol{U}_{2}.$$

---

From the inverse transform $$\left(\begin{array}{l}
\boldsymbol{U}_{1} \\
\boldsymbol{U}_{2}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\boldsymbol{I} & -\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1} \\
\mathbf{0} & \boldsymbol{I}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\boldsymbol{Y}_{1}-\boldsymbol{\mu}_{1} \\
\boldsymbol{Y}_{2}-\boldsymbol{\mu}_{2}
\end{array}\right),$$ $\boldsymbol{U}_{1}$ and $\boldsymbol{U}_{2}$ are independent, $\boldsymbol{Y}_{1}=\boldsymbol{\mu}_{1}+\boldsymbol{U}_{1}+\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{12} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{22}^{-1} \boldsymbol{U}_{2},\boldsymbol{Y}_{2}=\boldsymbol{\mu}_{2}+\boldsymbol{U}_{2}.$ I can not go further about this.I don't  know what's the formal definition about  $\boldsymbol{Y_{1}}|\boldsymbol{Y_{2}}\stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{=}\boldsymbol{X_{1}}|\boldsymbol{X_{2}}.$

Comment: I don't see what the confusion is: $Y_1 \mid U_2  \stackrel{d}{=} Y_1 \mid Y_2$ since $\mu_2$ is a constant and so it doesn't affect the conditional distribution.

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty I believe the problem is subtler than that.  Generally, even when $(U_1,U_2)=f(Y_1,Y_2)$ is a measurable one-to-one transformation, it is *not* the case that the conditional distributions $U_1\mid U_2$ and $Y_1\mid Y_2$ must be the same.  Out of this misconception arise many so-called "geometric paradoxes" in probability theory, such as the [Bertran Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

Comment: Hmm, I’m not sure why this would cause problems in this specific example; $\sigma(Y_2) = \sigma(U_2 + c) = \sigma(U_2)$ and so $P(Y_1 \in A \mid Y_2) = P(Y_1 \in A \mid U_2)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty I did not state that would cause problems, but only wished to point out that there indeed is something to demonstrate here: the result is not automatic.